# Find duplicate file in another directory

Tags: linux, bash, duplicate, fdupes

I have a file named: `f{number}.ext`

In another directory there exists a list of dirs:

- 001
- 002
- 003
- ....

Each of these dirs contains a list of files:

- f001.ext
- f002.ext
- ...

The file names are repeated in each directory, but these are different files.
I need to find this file (`f{number}.ext`) in the referred list of directories and get the root directory name — e.g. `003` — or print a message if the file is not found.

Can I use `fdupes` for this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for iNumb in '001' '002' '003' '004' '005'; do
  myFile=`ls */f${iNumb}.ext 2>&1`

  if [ "${myFile:0:2}" == "ls" ]
  then
    echo "File f${iNumb}.ext: File not found"
  else
    echo "File f${iNumb}.ext:" `dirname ${myFile}`
  fi
done
```

- The `2>&1` deals with the error message of ls when the file is not found (e.g. `ls: cannot access */f005.ext: No such file or directory`).
- The `if` test whether or string `myFile` starts with an `ls` (then we had an error) or not (then we found a file).
- `dirname` returns the directory. `basename` would return the file name.